# How can I access FTP through a linux-server SSH?

Tags: linux, git, ssh, server

I recently acquired a project from a former colleague, but the only information he gave me was the SSH key for a server and a bitbucket repository. I need to access the FTP of the server so I can change the files of the website.
I have zero experience with SSH or console commands. I have the repository but I don't know how to upload it. A friend of mine said that it's possible to pull a repo to the server, but I don't know how to even transcend in the folders of the server. I have just the console.

It says that the server's image is - ubuntu-1604-xenial-v20180127

And these are the only options I have - http://prntscr.com/p31inf

Also note that the website is running on Magento and I have no idea how it works. I'm a wordpress developer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- What you want is sftp: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-sftp-to-securely-transfer-files-with-a-remote-server
- So just use a ftp-client like filezilla and select sftp as protocol

Btw, magento is a little bit different than wordpress. Good luck ;)

Comment: Thanks! That worked perfectly and I'm now connected. But are there any tips to see where the website is located? I see the basic linux structure but is there a default location for webserver files?

Comment: Please close off-topic questions.